Supplying data to hyperref's pdfauthor: different command types give different results
The hyperref package allows a list of authors to be assigned to the pdfauthor option. For example, this works for me
\hypersetup{ pdfauthor={Me, Bobby McGee} }

The two authors are recognised in the input. They appear in my PDF reader as distinct authors and in the XMP metadata produced by pdflatex there are two items in the <dc:creator> sequence.
Unfortunately, when I do
\newcommand{\names}{Me, Bobby McGee}
\hypersetup{ pdfauthor={\names} }

I get just one author entry "Me, Bobby McGee" instead of two. Why does this happen?
My objective is to assign the list of authors from an Expl3 sequence. This is shown in the working example below. I have tried several different ways of passing the data to pdfauthor. None work.
When I use \hypersetup{ pdfauthor={\displayAuthors} } I get the same result as \hypersetup{ pdfauthor={\names} }. However, if I use \hypersetup{ pdfauthor={\displayAuthorsExpl} } no metadata is captured at all! Why is there a difference here between using a \newcommand and a \NewDocumentCommand?
Because the simple direct declaration of several authors works, there must surely be a way of automating things?
\DocumentMetadata{
    pdfversion=1.7,
    pdfstandard=A-3b,
}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\names}{Me, Bobby McGee}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_my_author_seq

\NewDocumentCommand \reportAuthor { m } {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_my_author_seq { #1 }
}

\newcommand{\displayAuthors} {
    \seq_use:Nn \l_my_author_seq {,~} 
}

\NewDocumentCommand\displayAuthorsExpl {} {
    \seq_use:Nn \l_my_author_seq {,~} 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\reportAuthor{Me}
\reportAuthor{Bobby McGee}
   
%% Choose one of these
%\hypersetup{ pdfauthor={Me, Bobby McGee} }
\hypersetup{ pdfauthor={\names} }
%\hypersetup{ pdfauthor={\displayAuthors} }
%\hypersetup{ pdfauthor={\displayAuthorsExpl} }

%% These show different things at the command line
%% However, the three lines printed on the document (below) are identical
%\show\names
%\show\displayAuthors
%\show\displayAuthorsExpl

\begin{document}
\names\par
\displayAuthors\par
\displayAuthorsExpl
\end{document}

I'm aware that pdfauthor has produced some discussion earlier. However, my concerns don't seem to be addressed.

\NewDocumentCommand creates a protected command that can not be expanded.

You need to expand \names before passing it to \hyersetup. Try \NewDocumentCommand\setpdfauthor{ m }{\hypersetup{pdfauthor={#1}}} \ExpandArgs{o}\setpdfauthor{\names}. If you are already working in expl3, it's probably best to define a function there that takes \l_my_author_seq and appropriately hands a list to \hypersetup.

Apart from this, yes hypersetup doesn't expand the argument of pdfauthor. But it could do that. Make a feature request at https://github.com/latex3/pdfresources/issues

@schtandard Your approach works :-) But I don't understand it. I did not find \ExpandArgs documented anywhere. Could you sketch out how to handle this in expl3, please?

@Blair It is in section 4 of usrguide.pdf which you can access with texdoc, on CTAN or elsewhere. (Part of the base LaTeX distribution.) Starts on page 19 in my version.

I don't yet understand how to fix this. If I replace \names with \displayAuthors in the suggestion from @schtandard, I still have the problem that only one author string is recognised by hypersetup. \ExpandArgs is not doing the same thing in this case.

try with \ExpandArgs{e} instead of \ExpandArgs{o}.

Your problem is one of expansion, see for example What is "expansion"? and What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands? When and why do we need \protect? for some info on that. \hypersetup does not expand its argument before looking for commas, so when you supply the value \names it finds no comma and concludes that there is only a single author. As Ulrike mentioned in the comments, you can make a feature request asking for that to change, but for now you have to do the expansion yourself before passing the author list to \hypersetup, for example
\NewDocumentCommand\setpdfauthor{ m }{\hypersetup{pdfauthor={#1}}}
\ExpandArgs{o}\setpdfauthor{\names}

or in the programming layer (given that the formatted list is in \g_blair_authornames_str)
\cs_new:Nn \__blair_set_pdfauthornames:n
  { \hypersetup { pdfauthor = { #1 } } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__blair_set_authornames:n { V }
\cs_new:Nn \blair_set_pdfauthornames:
  { \__blair_set_pdfauthornames:V \g_blair_authornames_str }

(or something like that).
Managing expansions like here is one of the great strengths of expl3. It should usually be done in the programming layer via \cs_generate_variant:Nn or directly using \exp_args:NV etc. but since much of LaTeX is not (yet) written in expl3, this functionality is also exposed as the user macro \ExpandArgs which I used above. \ExpandArgs{o} expands to (the equivalent of) \exp_args:No.

For reference, here's how you could do it in plain TeX (with the formatted list in \names, as in your question).
\def\@setpdfauthor#1{%
  \hypersetup{pdfauthor={#1}}%
}
\def\setpdfauthor{%
  \expandafter\@setpdfauthor\expandafter{\names}%
}


OK, thanks. I think I get it. However, my authors are in a sequence not a string. Therefore, I seem to need the e variant of \__blair_set_authornames:n (not V). I can then define a command that sets the metadata: \newcommand{\blairMetaAuthors} {  \__blair_set_authornames:e { \seq_use:Nn \l_my_author_seq {,~} } }. Have I understood correctly?

@Blair Yes, that's correct. As always, there are many ways to skin this cat, e.g. it may make sense to first format the sequence into a string that can be used multiple times. The crux of the issue is the expansion order, which is why my answer focuses on that. The details will depend on the rest of your code.

Just to be clear, here is what works for the code I posted in the question. It is based on the answer by Schtandard and comments.
\DocumentMetadata{
    pdfversion=1.7,
    pdfstandard=A-3b,
}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_my_author_seq

\NewDocumentCommand \reportAuthor { m } {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_my_author_seq { #1 }
}

\newcommand{\displayAuthors} {
    \seq_use:Nn \l_my_author_seq {,~} 
}

% Hyperref does not expand the argument to pdfauthor
% This private function does the expansion
\cs_new:Nn \__my_set_authormetadata:n
  { \hypersetup { pdfauthor = { #1 } } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__my_set_authormetadata:n { e }

% Command to assign author metadata 
\newcommand{\authorMetadata} { 
  \__my_set_authormetadata:e { \seq_use:Nn \l_my_author_seq {,~} }
%  \__my_set_authormetadata:e { \displayAuthors }    % This also works
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


% Load as many authors as required
\reportAuthor{Me}
\reportAuthor{Bobby McGee}

% Set the XMP element `pdfauthor`
\authorMetadata
   
\begin{document}
\displayAuthors\par
\end{document}

The PDF generated correctly identifies two authors in the dc:creator XMP element. PDF readers indicate these in the document properties.
